# PHP display memory exhausted

Tags: php, out-of-memory

I have a very long PHP script adapting multiple images and creating many arrays. At a certain moment I get the `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted` error at a very random line:

```
if (isset($pixels[$x1+1][$y1+1])) return Array($x1+1,$y1+1);
```

So I know the problem is not really this line. What I want to do is somehow print the amount of memory exhausted already at several places throughout my script, so I can optimize my code to exhaust less and so I can see which code blocks are really memory-intensive. To do so I would need something like:

```
echo $memorySizeUsed."<br />";
```

Is there a way to do so, or do I have to dig just randomly?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`memory_get_usage()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.memory-get-usage.php) to monitor memory usage:

```
echo "memory usage: " . memory_get_usage () . " bytes";
```